# How to perform Incremental refresh when making a star schema using Power BI transforms?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have a large table (FactSales) in Dw with following columns:

OrderDate|ProductID|OrderNumber|CustomerName|Amount

DateTable connects on date column to OrderDate

DimProduct connects on ProductID column to ProductID

Incremental refresh is configured on this table.

Now to improve this model in Power BI, I want to move the CustomerName to its own new dimension table (say DimCustomer). To achieve this, suppose I duplicate this fact table, then keep only the CustomerName column, remove duplicates, add an index column. Then merge the SalesFact table with DimCustomer.

At this point I'm unable to configure Incremental refresh for DimCustomer and FactSales table because the native query option is disabled (query doesn't fold).

So my intention to improve the model has the negative cost of not being able to incrementally refresh. How is this scenario (adding index column, and merge with another table) handled by Power BI engineers so that incremental refresh can be performed?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to inject the RangeStart/RangeEnd parameters before the first non-foldable query step.

Comment: Isn't it important that the last step shows native query?

Comment: Not really, unless you're using the build-in change detection functionality.  That's the only time the outermost query is used in folding.  The docs used to over-emphasize the role of query folding in incremental refresh.  I updated them recently to clarify. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/incremental-refresh-overview#supported-data-sources

Comment: I mean to ask whether it starts index from 1 at each refresh for the newly fetched data? Or will it rebuild the whole model at each refresh.

Comment: Each partition is loaded separately.  So your power query will run for each interval in your incremental refresh window separately.

Comment: So since partition are updated independantly, for the subsequent load, a new customer will get the ID 1 which is already occupied by an existing customer? Then it is fair to say incremental refresh isn't useful in my scenario?

Comment: Sounds like it.  It's generally difficult to create proper dimensions in PBI when they don't exist in the data source.  Maintaining dimensions really requires the ability to find and update a single row, which Power BI can't do.

Comment: I have given the steps to replicate this and shown that it doesn't work as expected here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75337384/incremental-refresh-not-working-as-expected-when-dimension-is-created-from-a-fac